# Tweet responses

Tags: twitter

If I go to the twitter page of someone I'm following, and click one some of their tweets, on the right column I can see responses. However, when I click on some of their tweets, I don't see responses, I just see other tweets that they made and how many people retweeted that tweet. Does that mean that there were no responses to these tweets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it could either be that particular tweet is not part of a conversation (i.e No one replied to it or the tweet itself isn't a reply) or it maybe part of a conversation but the other person has protected their tweets.

**EDIT**

**Protecting your Tweets**

To protect your tweets Log in to Twitter and navigate to your [Settings](http://twitter.com/settings/account).  Then scroll down and tick the check box `Protect my tweets`

[image: Protect Tweets]

Then click `Save` to confirm your changes.

Comment: How does someone protect their tweets?

Comment: @z-buffer - I have updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: What if you respond to someone's tweet with a protected tweet, and they retweet your tweet? What if others respond to a protected tweet, are those also hidden from a search?

Comment: @z-buffer - A protected tweet cannot be retweeted. If you respond to a protected tweet then the unprotected tweets are visible to everyone. The protected tweets will not be visible unless you have been approved to view them.

Comment: So a response to a protected tweet will be visible?

Comment: @z-buffer - Yes, the response will be visible but not the original protected tweet